# org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.FieldNotFoundException when using PowerMock.expectNew

Tags: mocking, junit4, easymock, powermock

I wanted to mock the following code using PowerMock:

```
ConnectionFactory rabbitMqFactory = createFactory();
com.rabbitmq.client.Connection connection = rabbitMqFactory.newConnection();
com.rabbitmq.client.Channel channel = con.createChannel();
com.rabbitmq.client.QueueingConsumer consumer = new com.rabbitmq.client.QueueingConsumer(channel);
```

However, when I mock the QueueingConsumer as expectNew:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({MyClass.class})
public class MyClassTester {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        QueueingConsumer consumer = createMock(QueueingConsumer.class);
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        // other code mock here ...
        PowerMock.expectNew(QueueingConsumer.class, Channel.class).andReturn(consumer);
        replayAll();
        myClass.callRabbitMq();
        verifyAll();
    }
}
```

I always get the following exception:

```
org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.FieldNotFoundException: No instance field of type "org.easymock.internal.MocksControl$MockType" could be found in the class hierarchy of org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.matcherstrategies.FieldTypeMatcherStrategy.notFound(FieldTypeMatcherStrategy.java:40)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.findSingleFieldUsingStrategy(WhiteboxImpl.java:509)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.findFieldInHierarchy(WhiteboxImpl.java:455)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getInternalState(WhiteboxImpl.java:578)
    at org.powermock.api.easymock.internal.invocationcontrol.EasyMockMethodInvocationControl.getMockType(EasyMockMethodInvocationControl.java:99)
    at org.powermock.api.easymock.internal.invocationcontrol.NewInvocationControlImpl.invoke(NewInvocationControlImpl.java:53)
    at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.newInstanceCall(MockGateway.java:191)
```

I just don't get it why. Is there something wrong with my code? I've rewritten it using different approaches but will always arrive at this error when using expectNew. Or is this a current issue for PowerMock release 1.5.1?

-thanks-

Answer (score 3):

What version of Easymock are you using? I got the same issue when I had 3.2 version of EasyMock, but using 3.1 worked OK. I believe Powermock 1.5.1 expects EasyMock 3.1 to be provided anyway, so this would be the correct version to use.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error when using the following jars:

**Jars**

- activemq-all-5.9.0.jar
- com.ibm.mq.headers-7.0.1.5.jar
- com.ibm.mq.jmqi-7.5.0.0.jar
- com.ibm.mqjms-7.5.0.0.jar
- javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar
- junit-4.10.jar
- powermock-easymock-1.5.1-full.jar
- com.ibm.mq-7.0.1.5.jar
- easymock-3.2.jar
- objenesis-2.1.jar
- cglib-nodep-2.2.jar
- easymockclassextension-2.4.jar
- com.ibm.disthub2-1.jar

**Error**

```
org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.FieldNotFoundException: No instance field of type "org.easymock.internal.MocksControl$MockType" could be found in the class hierarchy of org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.matcherstrategies.FieldTypeMatcherStrategy.notFound(FieldTypeMatcherStrategy.java:40)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.findSingleFieldUsingStrategy(WhiteboxImpl.java:509)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.findFieldInHierarchy(WhiteboxImpl.java:455)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getInternalState(WhiteboxImpl.java:578)
    at org.powermock.api.easymock.internal.invocationcontrol.EasyMockMethodInvocationControl.getMockType(EasyMockMethodInvocationControl.java:99)
    at org.powermock.api.easymock.internal.invocationcontrol.NewInvocationControlImpl.invoke(NewInvocationControlImpl.java:53)
    at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.newInstanceCall(MockGateway.java:191)
    at QueueService.createQueueConnection(QueueService.java:207)
    at QueueService.sendMessage(QueueService.java:93)
    at QueueServiceTest.testSendMessage(QueueServiceTest.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:94)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:118)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:101)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I fixed this error by replacing the easymock-3.2.jar with easymock-3.1.jar. Found here at official download site: http://easymock.org/Downloads.html